# do pairwise comparisons between all possible combinations

Tags: r

I have a matrix and I want to do pairwise comparisons between all possible combinations (unique):

data.frame

```
        A      B     C     D
 a      2      0     2     50
 b      1      3     1     2
 c      4      6     7     50
 d      1      3     8     2
...   ...     ...   ...   ...


library(utils)
combined <- combn(samples,2,simplify = FALSE)

combined
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "C"
...

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:length(combined)){
  cor <- sprintf(cor(dat$combined[[i]][1],dat$combined[[i]] [2]),fmt='%#.2g',method="spearman")
  smoothScatter (
        dat$combined[[i]][1],
        dat$combined[[i]][2],
        main=paste0("Spearman= ",cor),
      )
 }
dev.off()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in cor(dat$combined[[i]][1], dat$combined[[i]][2]) : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

Comment: You say `matrix` but you try to access rows and columns as if it's a data frame. `xm = matrix(1:4, 2); xdf = as.data.frame(xm);` Look at the difference between `xm[[1]]` and `xdf[[1]]`.

Comment: I would recommend setting `i` to 1 and trying to run smaller and smaller pieces of code inside your loop until you find the problems - the things that aren't as you expect. For example, `dat$combined[[i]][1]` makes it look like `dat` is a data frame with a column named `combined`, which happens to be a column of lists (because why else would you be using `[[` to access an element of a column), for which you want the first element of the first list. Which sounds nothing like the `dat` you show.

Comment: Okay, so then you want `dat[[combined[[i]][1]]]`, because `$` won't work with a string column name stored in a variable.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks a lot. it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I just got doing almost the exact same kind of thing, except with Cosine similarity instead or correlation:

```
set.seed(255)
mydata<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400), nrow = 20))
## 20x20 matrix

choices<-choose(20,2) #20 choose 2 possible pairs
combs<-combn(20,2) # create those pairs

COR<-NULL
A<-NULL
B<-NULL

  for(i in 1:choices) {
    nums<-combs[,i]
    COR[i]<-cor(mydata[,nums[1]], mydata[,nums[2]])
    A[i]<-nums[1]
    B[i]<-nums[2]
  }

COR.data<-data.frame(A,B,COR) #create a data.frame with the results
head(COR.data, 5)

A B       COR
1 2  0.246464
1 3  0.209621
1 4 -0.273593
1 5  0.380731
1 6  0.008158
```

In the resulting `data.frame` columns A and B are the columns of the `mydata` object that were compared.